# Nifi MergeRecord & MergeContent unable to merge avro flow fiels having different schema

Tags: json, avro, apache-nifi

I am using NiFi Flow as ListFile >> FetchFile >> SplitJson >> UpdateAttribute >> FlattenJson >> InferAvroSchema >> ConvertRecord >> MergeRecord >> PutParquet.

Json Input :

```
[{
       "Id": 1235,
        "Username": "fred1235",
        "Name": "Fred",
        "ShippingAddress": {
            "Address1": "456 Main St.",
            "Address2": "",
            "City": "Durham",
            "State": "NC"
        }

    },{

        "Id": 1236,
        "Username": "larry1234",
        "Name": "Larry",
        "ShippingAddress": {
            "Address1": "789 Main St.",
            "Address2": "",
            "City": "Durham",
            "State": "NC",
            "PostalCode": 277453
        },
        "Orders": [{
                "ItemId": 1111,
                "OrderDate": "11/11/2012"
            }, {
                "ItemId": 2222,
                "OrderDate": "12/12/2012"
        }]

}]
```

MergeRecord Processor not giving "Orders": array in merged file schema. Same issue with MergeContent processor.

Comment: Can you show the schema that is being generated by InferAvroSchema? and also, is the json input what is going into MergeRecord, or is that the example from the beginning of the flow?

Comment: { "type" : "record", "name" : "jsonRecord", "fields" : [ { "name" : "Id", "type" : "int", "doc" : "Type inferred from '1236'" }, { "name" : "Username", "type" : "string", "doc" : "Type inferred from '\"larry1234\"'" }, { "name" : "Name", "type" : "string", "doc" : "Type inferred from '\"Larry\"'" }, { "name" : "ShippingAddress_Address1", "type" : "string", "doc" : "Type inferred from '\"789 Main St.\"'" }, { "name" : "ShippingAddress_Address2", "type" : "string", "doc" : "Type inferred from '\"\"'" }, { "name" : "ShippingAddress_City", "type" : "string", "doc" : "Type inferred from '\"Durham

Comment: \"'" }, { "name" : "ShippingAddress_State", "type" : "string", "doc" : "Type inferred from '\"NC\"'" }, { "name" : "ShippingAddress_PostalCode", "type" : "int", "doc" : "Type inferred from '277453'" }, { "name" : "Orders", "type" : { "type" : "array", "items" : { "type" : "record", "name" : "Orders", "fields" : [ { "name" : "ItemId", "type" : "int", "doc" : "Type inferred from '1111'" }, { "name" : "OrderDate", "type" : "string", "doc" : "Type inferred from '\"11/11/2012\"'" } ] } }, "doc" : "Type inferred from '[{\"ItemId\":1111,\"OrderDate\":\"11/11/2012\"},

Comment: {\"ItemId\":2222,\"OrderDate\":\"12/12/2012\"}]'" } ] }

Comment: above is avro schema for one avro flow file and another is.. { "type" : "record", "name" : "jsonRecord", "fields" : [ { "name" : "Id", "type" : "int", "doc" : "Type inferred from '1237'" }, { "name" : "Username", "type" : "string", "doc" : "Type inferred from '\"fred12356\"'" }, { "name" : "Name", "type" : "string", "doc" : "Type inferred from '\"Fred\"'" },

Comment: { "name" : "ShippingAddress_Address1", "type" : "string", "doc" : "Type inferred from '\"456 Main St.\"'" }, { "name" : "ShippingAddress_Address2", "type" : "string", "doc" : "Type inferred from '\"\"'" }, { "name" : "ShippingAddress_City", "type" : "string", "doc" : "Type inferred from '\"Durham\"'" }, { "name" : "ShippingAddress_State", "type" : "string", "doc" : "Type inferred from '\"NC\"'" } ] }

Comment: after merging wih mergerecord it is missing  { "name" : "Orders", "type" : { "type" : "array", "items" : { "type" : "record", "name" : "Orders", "fields" : [ { "name" : "ItemId", "type" : "int", "doc" : "Type inferred from '1111'" }, { "name" : "OrderDate", "type" : "string", "doc" : "Type inferred from '\"11/11/2012\"'" } ] } }, "doc" : "Type inferred from '[{\"ItemId\":1111,\"OrderDate\":\"11/11/2012\"}

Comment: this part of the schema of flow files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using SplitJson and FlattenJson, you could use [JoltTransformJSON](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON/index.html) with the following ChainR spec to flatten the whole thing without splitting:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "ShippingAddress": {
          "Address1": "[&2].ShippingAddress_Address1",
          "Address2": "[&2].ShippingAddress_Address2",
          "City": "[&2].ShippingAddress_City",
          "State": "[&2].ShippingAddress_State"
        },
        "Orders": {
          "*": {
            "ItemId": "[&3].Orders_&1_ItemId",
            "OrderDate": "[&3].Orders_&1_OrderDate"
          }
        },
        "*": "[&1].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Not sure what the ConvertRecord is used for, but you shouldn't need the MergeRecord anymore. If this isn't the output you're looking for, please let me know what you're expecting (for both records, the one with and without an Orders field) and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: tried JoltTransformationJSON with above chain. But after infering avro schema I am using convertRecord to convert json to avro and store to as parquet on hdfs. but here convertRecord is giving error that is : org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Failed to create schema from the Schema Text after evaluating FlowFile Attributes
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.AbstractRecordProcessor$1.process(AbstractRecordProcessor.java:132)
        at

Comment: Are you sure the correct Avro schema is in an attribute and that is the attribute being evaluated in the Schema Text property?

Comment: Yes Avro Schema is correct. After Spliting the JSON ConvertRecord is woking properly. but again missing orders array while merging with mergeRecord :(

Comment: If you’re using Split you don’t need ConvertRecord , that was supposed to replace the need for Split and Merge. I’ll take a look using your flow to see what’s going on

Comment: if I do not use ConvertRecord then MergeRecord is giving me error : **org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$AppendWriteException: java.lang.NullPointerException: null of int in field Orders_0_ItemId of test-data-lavel-two.json**

Comment: NiFi Flow is : **ListFile>>FetchFile>>JoltTransformJson>>SplitJson>>InferAvroSchema>>MergeRecord>>PutParquet**